# Java runs out of memory, even though I give it plenty!

Tags: java, linux, memory

So, I'm running a java server (specifically Winstone: http://winstone.sourceforge.net/ )

Like this:
java -server -Xmx12288M -jar /usr/share/java/winstone-0.9.10.jar --useSavedSessions=false --webappsDir=/var/servlets --commonLibFolder=/usr/share/java

This has worked fine in the past, but now it needs to load a bunch more stuff into memory than it has before.

The odd part is that, according to 'top', it has 15.0g of VIRT(ual memory) and it's RES(ident set) is 8.4g.  Once it hits 8.4g, the CPU hangs at 100% (even though it's loading from disk), and eventually, I get Java's OutOfMemoryError.  Presumably, the CPU hanging at 100% is Java doing garbage collection.

So, my question is, what gives?  I gave it 12 gigs of memory!  And it's only using 8.2 gigs before it throws in the towel.  What am I doing wrong?

Oh, and I'm using 
java version "1.6.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_07-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0-b23, mixed mode)

on Linux.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: If those 8.4GB are placed in the "middle" of those 12GB, and the program is trying to allocate a 3GB block in one go, it may be the case that there doesn't exist such a block of contiguous, free memory. That makes the GC kick in to try and free some stuff, but if it can't free enough memory to find that block, then it's going to go down even though it should technically be free.

Comment: The things it's adding aren't particularly big.  It's a bunch of text files ( bunch =~ 25-50,000 ).  So it's not like it's trying to allocate a big block of memory.  Though maybe it's hitting some fragmentation problems...?  GC should clean that up, though, right?

Comment: From comments below: You could try running *another* memory-hog process before this one statrs running. If your server crashes in the same way, but at a lower memory size (as I think it will), that will at least show that lack of OS memory *can* cause the same issue that you're seeing. (Of course, it won't *prove* that that's the real problem.)

Comment: That is a HECKUVALOT of memory!!! Are you sure things are as optimized as they can get?

Answer (score 8):

> The odd part is that, according to 'top', it has 15.0g of VIRT(ual memory) and it's RES(ident set) is 8.4g. Once it hits 8.4g, the CPU hangs at 100% (even though it's loading from disk), and eventually, I get Java's OutOfMemoryError.

I think you are misinterpreting things.   The "-Xmx12288M" option does not reserve physical memory.  Rather it sets an upper limit on the size of the Java heap.  Java also needs memory for non-heap objects; e.g. permgen space, code space, memory mapped files, etcetera.
It is quite plausible for a 12g heap + the non-heap memory used/shared by the JVM to add up to 15g.

The 8.4g reported by top as RES is the amount of physical memory that is currently being used to run the JVM.  It is not directly related to the size of your Java heap.  Indeed, you would expect the RES number to move up and down as different processes' pages are swapped in and out by the OS virtual memory system.  This is entirely outside the control of the JVM.

> Presumably, the CPU hanging at 100% is Java doing garbage collection.

Yes.  That's typically what happens.

I can think of three possible explanations:

- Most likely, the operating system is unable to give your JVM the memory it is asking for because there is not enough swap disk space.  For example if you have 2 processes with 15g of virtual memory each, that's 30gb.  Given that you have 24g of physical memory, you will need at least 8g (probably more) of swap space.  If the amount of physical memory allocatable to user processes + the amount of swap space is less than the total virtual space used by processes the OS will start refusing requests by the JVM to expand the heap.  You can run "swapon -s" to see how much swap space is available / in use.
- Your application may *really* be using all of the 12g of heap that you've said it can use, and that is not enough.  (Maybe you've got a storage leak.  Maybe it really needs more memory.)
- It is also possible (but highly unlikely) that someone has set a process limit.  You can use the shell builtin 'ulimit' command to see if this has been done; refer to "man ulimit" for details.

**EDIT**

- If you use the `-verbose:gc` and `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` options, the GC might give you more clues as to what is happening.  In particular, it will tell you how big the Java heap really is when you run out of memory.
- You could write a little Java app that simply allocates and doesn't free lots of memory, and see how much it manages to allocate before falling over with an OOM error when run with the same options as you are currently using.  (I don't think this will tell you anything new.  **EDIT 2** actually, it *will* tell you something if you run it in the way that @Dan suggests! )
- If (as seems likely) the real problem is that you don't have enough swap space, there is nothing you can do on the Java side to fix this.  You need to reconfigure your system to have more swap space.  Refer to your Linux system administration documentation, the `man` pages for `swapon`, `mkswap` etcetera.

Comment: Hm.  I doubt the 8.4 gigs is used by the JVM.  It scales linearly as we open files, which I'm storing in the heap.  I don't have any swap space set up, though.  I wonder if that might be it.  There's also definitely not a process limit.

Are there any other neat things I can pass to the JVM (a la '-Xmx12288M') to get it to behave as I'd like (or at least give me a better indication as to why it's failing)?

Comment: Keep in mind that simple things like str += otherString; can require atleast the length of (str + otherString )*2 of memory, if that can't be allocated you get oom exceptions. Might matter if str is really large. Same thing if you're shuffling around arrays to grow stuff. Or using libraries who does this under the hood out of your sight.

Comment: @spitzanator: I've responded to this on your question, above.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes OutOfMemorError doesn't mean object heap is used up -- but something else. Was there any other info on the error stack?

In particular, the JVM needs a bunch of memory/address-space separate from the heap space. At some point, giving the process more object heap can leave less space for this other pool -- paradoxically making OOMEs more likely with larger '-Xmx' settings!

Memory-mapped files can eat a lot of address space; failing to close files properly can leave this space allocated until GC/finalization, which happens at an unpredictable time. Also, having a larger heap puts off GC/finalization -- meaning this native address space may stay reserved longer, so again: larger heaps can mean more frequent OOMEs due to depleted other memory.

You can also use '-Xms' of the same value to force all heap address space to be grabbed immediately at startup -- perhaps triggering the failure at a more convenient/understandable/reproducible stage.

Finally, there's also a threshold at which an OOME is thrown even if no memory request has failed -- but GC is taking "too much" time, indicating garbage being created as fast as it's being collected, probably in a tight loop. A big inefficient load-from-disk where lots of garbage is created for a small amount of retained data might cause this. Look up [GC overhead limit] for details.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to the latest version of java (1.6.0_17)?

Comment: Good call.  I upgraded, but it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dumb question, but are you sure that your swap partition has at least 15GB free when the program starts?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  The machine has 24 gigs of RAM.  I allocated 12 to this process and 12 to another (both of them need their 12).

Not a dumb question at all.

Comment: But what about swap? Do you have any swap space configured, or do you run entirely from RAM? If you're running entirely from RAM, then unless *Linux* knows it should dedicate 12GB to the process (and I'm not sure how you'd do that), then you may be running out of physical memory due to contention from other processes.

Comment: There's no contention on the machine for RAM.  I've looked, and there's still free RAM when the java process explodes.

Answer (score 0):

And just to confirm, it ain't the PermGen space running out right?

Comment: The error isn't on the PermGen space, no. At least the exception doesn't say so...

Answer (score 0):

> The odd part is that, according to
>   'top', it has 15.0g of VIRT(ual
>   memory) and it's RES(ident set) is
>   8.4g. Once it hits 8.4g, the CPU hangs at 100% (even though it's loading from
>   disk), and eventually, I get Java's
>   OutOfMemoryError. Presumably, the CPU
>   hanging at 100% is Java doing garbage
>   collection.

I would guess that java has to use that much memory that it decides (or is forced) to use disk space for your data. Now the next time it has to collect garbage it has to use IO to do this. Doing garbage collection on disk is rather expensive for sure. And because you have that much objects the garbage collector may jump in again and again. This may be why your CPU is at 100% ... doing garbage collection for ever.

As Stephen has said **-verbose:gc** and **-XX:+PrintGCDetails** will give more hints.

But apart from this, maybe it will pay of to invest in an implementation that has not to load all the files at once? Working at the limit of your memory doesn't look like a winning strategy.